# How to get IOS like look and feel in QML Style

Tags: ios, qml, qt5, qt6

I'm trying to port an iPad application from QT 5.12.11 to QT 6.4.2, and I cant get the UI to look as it was before.

this is the look I want with native IOS styled dropdown and feel (which I am getting in Qt 5.12.11)

[image]

this is the look I currently have

[image]

I have tried `import QtQuick.Controls.iOS` but still my dropdown doesn't look like native IOS like [https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-quick-controls-2-ios-style]

I have tried `import QtQuick.Controls.Material` and `import QtQuick.Controls.Universal` but still my dropdown doesn't look as expected.

My code is as follow:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Rectangle {
    Flickable{id: playerEdit
        // ...
        Rectangle { id: playerEditCanvas
            // ...
            Column { id: playerEditColumn
                // ...
                Rectangle { id: playerEditPrimaryDetailsRow
                    // ...
                    Column { id: playerEditDemoColumn
                        // ...
                        Rectangle { id: playerEditAccount
                            Text {
                                text: "account"
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                font {
                                    family: "SF UI Display"
                                    styleName: "Light"
                                    pixelSize: 14
                                }
                                color: "#0077fe"
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            }

                            ComboBox { id: playerEditAccountField
                                width: 501
                                height: 42
                                anchors.left: playerEditAccountLabel.right
                                anchors.leftMargin: 1

                                textRole: "rostername"
                                model: ListModel { id: playerEditAccountModel
                                    Component.onCompleted: {// ...}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                    // ...
                }
                // ...
            }
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: can you share the code snippet so we can check

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, I've updated my question with code snippet, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve that same look, you will have to use the Menu from the Qt Quick Labs module: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-platform-menu.html, which will draw a native picker, like the one you want.

The ComboBox implementation for the iOS style doesn't use a picker, but pops a menu instead, similar to pull-downs in iOS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiWa9.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `Tumbler` (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html).

In the following example, I customized `ComboBox` `popup` replacing it with a customized one based on `Tumbler`. I added customizations, like hardcoding the position to be relative to my parent `Page` making relative references to `myApp`. I also added `Cancel` and `Done` buttons based on your screenshot. I am not a native iOS person, so, I am judging the UI/UX based on the screenshots you've supplied.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: myApp
    AppComboBox {
        model: [
            "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"
        ]
    }
}

// AppComboBox.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ComboBox {
    id: appComboBox
    popup: Popup {
        id: popup
        y: myApp.height - height
        width: myApp.width
        height: myApp.height / 2
        padding: 0
        background: Rectangle { color: "#eee" }
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 0
            Frame {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "#ddd"
                    border.color: "#aaa"
                }
                padding: 1
                RowLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    Button {
                        text: qsTr("Cancel")
                        palette.buttonText: "#08f"
                        onClicked: popup.close()
                    }
                    Button {
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                        palette.buttonText: "#08f"
                        text: qsTr("Done")
                        onClicked: {
                            appComboBox.currentIndex = tumbler.currentIndex;
                            popup.close()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Frame {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                padding: 1
                Tumbler {
                    id: tumbler
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    model: appComboBox.model
                    currentIndex: appComboBox.currentIndex
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

You may also want to check out what's Qt Quick Controls 2: iOS Style in Qt6.4 - https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-quick-controls-2-ios-style

Comment: Ive tried what you suggested, but still this is not how i want it to be.

I want it to be something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/0wTXjoY) 

this is how [your suggestion turned out](https://imgur.com/a/rqrlTY6)

Comment: the control you want to use is Tumbler. But, because you aren't on iOS, you need to spend the effort to position and style it. I've updated the answer, but, the principal is the same as my original answer. You take the burden to style as much as you want. You need to spend time an effort to get the look you want. There is, obviously, some kind of refactor needed, so, the example is just a crude demonstration of how the control works, but, not intended to be used in production, since, a lot more code would be required.